# jdbc connection error with oracle

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

I am unable to connect to oracle database using jdbc.

Error:
Could not connect to database at jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost.localdomain:1521:orcl (Username: system, Password: tiger)

However, I can connect it using sqlplus command.

Here is the log:

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
Version = Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1
Testing Database Connection ...
  -- Failure! java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Here is the listener.ora:

```
 LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /home/oracle/app/oracle
```

Output of lsnrctl:

```
Listening Endpoints Summary...
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=::1)(PORT=1521)))
 Services Summary...
 Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
 Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
 Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
 Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
 The command completed successfully
```

Contents of tnsnames.ora:

```
 ORCL =
   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

I am using Oracle 11g, glassfish server 2.1, Redhat linux enterprise edition 6.

Any help would be really appreciated.

--Sam

Comment: can u provide stacktrace??

Comment: Prabhakar: I have past the log contents by editing the question.

Comment: Here it seem to be your host name or port number is wrong. did u check whether the user having the access??? can u post sample connection code??

Comment: here it is:sqlplus system/tiger@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Dec 6 17:16:44 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>

Comment: Please put new information in the question, not in comments, as it's hard to read and keep track of. How is `orcl` defined in your `tnsnames.ora` file? The host, port and service name you use for JDBC need to match those. Are you running Glassfish on the same server you're running SQL*Plus? (Incidentally, it's odd that you're connecting as `system`, particularly through JDBC; you shouldn't use `sys` or `system` schemas for your own tables etc., you should create a new user and use that instead).

Comment: @alex: added required files contents in the question. I have tried test_user that I created but no luck.

Comment: I thought what you have would work, but can you try the [thin service name syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#JJDBC28292) instead, i.e.: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost.localdomain:1521/orcl`? I'm still assuming Java is running on the same host as the DB.

Comment: @alexpoole: Got same error with this syntax as well. Yes java is in the same machine

Comment: Your listener only seems to be using IPv6 (from `HOST=::1`); [from the docs again](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#JJDBC28289), the 11g JDBC driver supports IPv6, but perhaps your JVM doesn't, or is using using the IPv4 address instead? Not sure how to check or resolve that though. I guess you could try giving the host as `[::1]` but not sure. Otherwise check your JDBC driver version and if Glassfish supports IPv6; or change the listener to use IPv4 too?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `localhost.localdomain` with `localhost` in the connection string, i.e.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
```

I too get a `The Network Adapter could not establish the connection` error if I use `localhost.localdomain` as the address, and it goes away if I use just `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Test :

```
 telnet localhost 1521
```

and if it does not work

Set iptables :

https://exploringspatial.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/installing-oracle-sql-developer/